# "dashboard"-named PHP file doesn't get included

Tags: plugin-development, dashboard, filesystem

I've made a simple *"test plugin"* to demonstrate the issue:

```
my-test-plugin/
├─ includes/
│  └─ dashboard.php
└─ main.php
```

```
 <?php // dashboard.php
 echo '<h1>Dashboard</h1>';
```

```
<?php // main.php
/**
* Plugin Name: My Test Plugin
*/
add_action('admin_menu', 'myTestPlugin_onAdminMenu');
function myTestPlugin_onAdminMenu() {
  add_menu_page('My Dashboard', 'My Test Plugin', 'manage_options', 'my-test-plugin', 'myTestPlugin_displayDashboardPage');
}
function myTestPlugin_displayDashboardPage() {
  require_once 'includes/dashboard.php';
}
```

This plugin only adds a menu item labeled `My Test Plugin`, that displays the "dashboard" page. It works perfectly on my development Windows machine; but surprisingly, it doesn't work on my online web-hosting service (LiteSpeed Web server running PHP 7.3.25, Wordpress 5.6.2)!

When I change the name of `dashboard.php` to anything else (e.g. `dashboard1.php`), it works with no problems at all! What could be the problem here and how may I fix it?!

Comment: It could be the require_once I suppose: maybe there's something else in the code e.g. a mu-plugin added by your host that also has a `require_once 'includes/dashboard.php';` meaning a different dashboard? But obviously they should be different files so not conflict.

Comment: "it doesn't work" - what happens exactly? Warning and/or fatal error? No file included? Or is the wrong file being included? Since you are passing a relative path, it's going to search the `include_path` - which could be different on the live site.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress has a file with the same name at [`wp-admin/includes/dashboard.php`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/includes/dashboard.php). Since you are using `require_once` PHP will not load a file if it already has been loaded.

The fact that your setup works locally, but not on your remote server, suggests that is has something to do with PHP server set-up. Locally `require_once` recognizes the different paths to the two files, your web server does not. So, I would try explicitly [including your plugin's directory](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/plugin_dir_path/) in the call. Like this:

```
require_once (plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'includes/dashboard.php');
```